# AngularJS Cookie Manager

Tags: javascript, angular.js

Just looking for an initial steer on my AngularJS implementation.

**Background**

Started work on a clients new site which uses a popular CMS as the backend and AngularJS has been chosen as the client side framework.

**Functionality**

Build a simple control that will manage alerts generated from the CMS.

- If the alert has been accepted already, remove the alert.
- If not, leave there and attach to the 'alertToggle' to save the
  cookie when it's clicked and remove the html.

**Note**

To keep a clean separation between backend and front-end I am avoiding logic in the HTML like ng-click="toggle" and instead using my custom alertToggle directive to achieve this. Same thing with not using ng-class for toggling alert--active.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

angular.module('alert', ['ngCookies'])
    .controller('alertController', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
        $scope.is_active = true;
        $scope.cookie_key = null;
        $scope.cookie_expiry = new Date(new Date().setYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 2));
        $scope.initalizeFromCookie = function () {
            if ($scope.cookie_key !== null &&
                    $cookieStore.get($scope.cookie_key)) {
                $scope.is_active = false;
            }
        };
        $scope.toggle = function (override) {
            var is_active = typeof override === 'boolean' ? override : !$scope.is_active;
            if (!is_active) {
                $scope.saveCookie();
            }
            return ($scope.is_active = is_active);
        };
        $scope.saveCookie = function () {
            if ($scope.cookie_key !== null) {
                $cookieStore.put($scope.cookie_key, true, { expires: $scope.cookie_expiry });
            }
        };
    })
 .directive('alert', function () {
        return {
            scope: true,
            controller: 'alertController',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
                if ('id' in attrs && $scope.cookie_key === null) {
                    $scope.cookie_key = 'synergy.alert.' + attrs.id;
                    $scope.initalizeFromCookie();
                }
                if ($element.hasClass('alert--active')) {
                    $scope.toggle(true);
                }
                $scope.$watch('is_active', function (is_active) {
                    $element.toggleClass('alert--active', is_active);
                });
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('cookieAlert', function () {
        return {
            scope: true,
            controller: 'alertController',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
                $scope.cookie_key = 'synergy.alert.cookie-usage';
                $scope.initalizeFromCookie();
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('alertToggle', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
                $element.on('click touchend', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.toggle();
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```